# How to query all information related to one entry?

Tags: json, mongodb, find

*How would I write a query to obtain just information relating to Carl?*

```
      { 
     "t" : 0,
    "member" : [
                     {   "name": "Carl",
                            "ad": 
                           {
                                "firstline" : 123,
                                "secondline": 456
                            }
                       },
                     {   "name": "John",
                            "ad": 
                           {
                                "firstline" : 345,
                                "secondline": 1256
                            }
                       }
                       ]
}
{
  "t" : 1,
    "member" : [
                     {   "name": "Carl",
                            "ad": 
                           {
                                "firstline" : 1323,
                                "secondline": 4536
                            }
                       },
                     {   "name": "John",
                            "ad": 
                           {
                                "firstline" : 3245,
                                "secondline": 123456
                            }
                       }
                       ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
    { 
         "t" : 0,
        "member" : [
                         {   "name": "Carl",
                                "ad": 
                               {
                                    "firstline" : 123,
                                    "secondline": 456
                                }
                           }
                           ]
}
{

        "t" : 1,
        "member" : [
                         {   "name": "Carl",
                                "ad": 
                               {
                                    "firstline" : 1323,
                                    "secondline": 4536
                                }
                           }                 
                           ]
    }
```

What I tried:

```
db.people.find("member.name" :"Carl")
```

But it did not output the desired information, and when having more t, the data is not in chronological order. And when exporting the data to a new JSON file the information loses its structure, meaning there are no newlines between the entries. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator for projection part of your `find()` method to specify array filtering condition:

```
db.people.find({ "member.name": "Carl" }, { member: { $elemMatch: { name: "Carl" } }, t: 1 })
```

Comment: I want to have also the information about the "t" included. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: @xava yes, you need to extend the projection I've just modified my answer